# How to call an action from another slice in the redux toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

The modal windows interaction logic is in modalSlice. userSlice contains the code for an asynchronous request to the server to get chat data. After getting the data, I want to open modal window. The window opening function is in modalSlice.showChat(). How to call this function?

```js
const reducer = combineReducers({
  mapSlice: mapSlice,
  userSlice: userSlice,
  modalSlice: modalSlice,
})
```

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userSlice',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {... },
  extraReducers: {         
    [fetchData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {       
       // How to execute the function showChat() of the reducer
       // from modalSlice from this slice function useSlice?
    }
  }
})
```

- `dispatch` - cannot be called
- `state.modalSlice.showChat()` - not working

UPD : Can I change the state in modal modalSlice directly from userSlice after receiving the data? For example state.modalSlice.chatOpen = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question right you want to dispatch showChat after that data has been fetched.

Since fetchData is an **Async Thunk** you can **make use of the thunk api to use dispatch directly** from the thunk where the data is fetched

**Here is how it can be done**

```
export const fetchData = createAsyncThunk('userSlice/fetchData', async (params, {dispatch}) => {
  const result = await getData()
  //here you can check if result is what you want and dispatch accordingly
  if (result)
  dispatch(showChat(result))
  return result
})
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Can I change the state in modal Slice directly from userSlice after receiving the data? For example state.modalSlice.chatOpen = true

Comment: i need to change value in modalSlice like modalSlice.chatOpen = true. Code state.chatOpen = true - dont working in userSlice

Comment: sorry my previous comment was wrong, u can do state.chatOpen = true inside of the showChat reducer inside of the modalSlice, So when you are doing dispatch chatOpen becomes true accordingly